# Custom Validation in Add form of datatables with jeditable plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, datatables, jeditable

I have validation working for editing fields in the datatable, I have validation working for fields in the add form that only need to be required.  My problem is in the add form for the table, I have a field that needs to use a custom validation.  So I attempted setting up a custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("invalidTags", function(value, element){
    return value.match(/[^A-Z_.]/);
}, 'Tags may only contain ALL CAPS characters, underscores, or periods');
```

And attempted to hook the form field up to it

```
$("formAddNewRowTags").validate({
    rules: {
        tag: {
            required: true,
            invalidTags: false
        }
    }
 });
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Should I be putting a validate call inside the .makeEditable definition of

```
"sAddNewRowFormId" : "formAddNewRowTags"
```

instead?